# How to set icon in column from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, tabulator

I am trying to change the icon displayed in a column from an ajax call when the table is first rendered.
It works perfectly if I only have:

```
 return "<i class='fas fa-eye fa-xs'></i>";
```

Here is the column setup

```
{title:"Review",formatter:reviewIcon, width:40,  headerVertical:true, align:"center", cellClick:reviewCellClick },
```

My ajax call is pretty simple, maybe not the best but it gets the result i'm after.
The returned value is either 0 or something else. I only care about the 0.

```
var reviewIcon = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){ //plain text value
           var cell = cell.getData();
           var ag = cell.accessgroups;
           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.open("GET", "includes/getaccessgroups.php?ag="+ag, true);
           xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
              var returned = xhr.response;
              if(returned < 1 ){
               return "<i class='fas fa-unlink fa-xs'></i>";
                    }
              else {
                return "<i class='fas fa-eye fa-xs'></i>";
                    }
               }
           }
         xhr.send();
  // return "<i class='fas fa-eye fa-xs'></i>";
};
```

Basically I want it to show unlinked if it's a 0 and eye if its something else.

If the return value is 0, then display `fa-unlink` otherwise display `fa-eye`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: absolutely correct.. I've now worked out how to close them.

Comment: That is great, thanks :) Now, can you clarify this please? "*if it's a 0 and eye if its something else"*. What do you mean by "eye"? I noticed there are `fa-eye` and maybe others, but unsure what you meant by what you wrote.

Comment: my apologies for not explaining...If the return value is = 0, then display fa-unlink othereise display fa-eye

Comment: Just add a JS fiddle example and show what needs to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it in this way im afraid, formatters in Tabulator must be synchronous in order for the table to be rendered quickly *(otherwise the table would have to make a request before it could render each row which would make the table really stuttery as you scroll)*.

This means that the formatter will finish executing before any ajax requests return.  The correct approach would be to update the data before it is loaded into the table with the correct vaulue for each row.